# Injective map on coordinate ring implies surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism between two affine varieties over an algebraically closed field $K$.

I believe that if the corresponding morphism of $K-$algebras, $f^\ast:K[Y]\rightarrow K[X]$ is injective, it is not necessarily true that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ must be surjective but I have yet to come up with a counterexample.

Is there such a counterexample?

Comment: What definition of *affine variety* are you using?

Comment: My definition of an affine variety is a variety that is isomorphic to an irreducible algebraic set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the inclusion $k[x] \subset k[x, x^{-1}]$. The corresponding map on $k$-points ($k$ algebraically closed) is also an inclusion, namely $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{ 0 \} \subset \mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: What is true is that a map of rings is monic iff the corresponding map of affine varieties is an epi —simply because of the anti-equivalence of categories between that of rings and that of affine varieties. In Qiaochu's example, the map of rings is both monic and epic,, so the map of varieties is both monic and epic.

Comment: In particular, one can fix the statement of the question by replacing *surjective* by *epi*, because monomorphism of rings are simply injective maps.

Comment: Is the fact that k be algebraically closed necessary here?

Comment: @Victor: if $k$ isn't algebraically closed, you should clarify what you mean by a surjective map of $k$-varieties.

Comment: This example doesn't work if one defines affine varieties to be isomorphic to irreducible algebraic sets. Is there such a simple example in this case?

Comment: @Victor: why not? $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is a perfectly good irreducible algebraic set (in $\mathbb{A}^2$).

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was momentarily confused by the fact that $\mathbb{A}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is not irreducible.

Answer (score 8):

Given a morphism of rings $\phi:A\to B$ and the corresponding morphism of affine schemes $\sideset {^a}{} \phi=f:Spec (B)\to Spec(A)$, we have the equivalence: $$ f (Spec(B))\:  \text {is dense  in}\:  Spec(A)\iff   \text {Ker } (\phi) \subset \text {Nil} (A)$$  From this   it is very easy to find injective morphisms of rings $\phi:A\to B$ with associated non surjective morphisms $ f:Spec (B)\to Spec(A)$.

For example if $A$ is a domain and $0\neq a\in A$, then the inclusion morphism $\phi:A\to A_a=A[\frac {1}{a}]$ yields the inclusion $\sideset {^a}{} \phi=f:Spec (A_a)\to Spec(A)$, which is not surjective as soon as  $a$ is not an invertible element of $A$. (Qiaochu's example is of that type)